# Не работает пагинация wordpress, если у страницы выбран свой шаблон

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Доброй ночи!
Не работает пагинация на странице у которой выбран свой шаблон, она отображается но при клике на страницу 2 например, вылезает 404 ошибка, перепробовал плагины, много разных примеров, но почему то все равно не срабатывает, буду очень признателен за помощь.
На данный момент код такой:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'page' => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>

Здесь выводим контент

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

posts_pagination();

/*
 * Постраничная навигация
 */
function posts_pagination(){
    global $wp_query;
    $nav = get_the_posts_pagination( $args = array(
         'show_all' => false,
         'prev_next' => true,
         'end_size' => 2,
         'mid_size' => 2,
         'before_page_number' => '',
         'after_page_number' => '',
         'prev_text' => '‹',
         'next_text' => '›',
    ));
    $nav = preg_replace('#(role)=".+?"#s', '', $nav);
    $nav = preg_replace('~<h2.*?h2>~', '', $nav);
    $nav = str_replace('<a ', '<a rel="nofollow" ', $nav);
    echo $nav;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, оказалось category было переименовано в posts, а slug страницы был такой же, из-за этого вылезала 404 ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Весь интернет обшарил и только благодаря вам нашел реаллизацию пагинации на сайте!!! Не один код не помогал!